# Nixtamalization: Am I doing it right?

Tags: chemistry, mexican-cuisine, corn

It's been a few years since I nixtamalizated the last time with the help of my Chilean friend.
Now I'm on my own and due to several contradicting information on the internet a little lost. Maybe someone can advice me on what and if I did something wrong.

For tonight I would like to prepare Polenta and do Nixtamalization with the flour before. I got pure calcium hydroxide from the pharmacy and used the following recipe:

- 250g Polenta Flour
- 1l Warm Water
- 1 stacked Tea Spoon of Calcium Hydroxide

First I dissolved the Ca(OH)2 in the water and then added the polenta flour in the legía, stirring gently. Now, after 30 minutes there is a white layer on the flour (picture 2).
The scent of it is really nice (very corny).

Ideally I'd wash it out tonight (after around 8h) and boil it.

As there are several recipes on how to do the Nixtamalization, I'm not sure if what I did is correct (I'm very careful. Some suggested to use a whole cup of Ca(OH)2 for two cups of corn - that's probably too much). Maybe someone can answer my questions:

- Are the amounts correct?
- Is it correct I'm not boiling the polenta in the legía?
- What is that white layer on my polenta?
- I haven't read many articles on nixtamalizating polenta flour. Has anyone ever tried that?
- Should I stir it once in a while or just leave it?
- I won't be able to eat the whole 250g of Polenta tonight. How to store it? Keep it in the legía or wash the whole and keep the wet polenta?

[image: Added Polenta]
[image: White layer]

Comment: Polenta isn't made with nixtamalized corn, it's basically just regular corn flour in hot water & stir; I always thought nixtamalization had to be done to the whole grains & the flour ground once dried. Living in the UK, you can buy polenta-style corn anywhere, but true masa harina is a nightmare to find.

Comment: "Polenta isn't made with nixtamalized corn" - that's why I'm doing it

Comment: Let me try another way - If it's made with nixtamalized corn, it's not polenta, it is, if anything, grits. btw, you're supposed to mix the lime with the water, leave it 12 hours then take the 'water' from the top, leaving the solids that sink & throw them out. You nixtamalize the corn with just the liquid. Yours looks like you've got the solids mixed in with the corn. That sounds very scary!

Comment: You can make polenta with nixtamalized corn, it's not common, but it is certainly possible, and likely delicious.  However, I do agree that you need to start with whole, dried kernels.

Comment: this is the nixtamalization process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixtamalization#/media/File:Flowchart_of_Nixtamalization_process.svg

Comment: @Luciano - I'm very much aware of the process. Due to the fact I need a slight clarification on the amounts and on how to deal I've posted my question. Your image deals with the default-case which does not apply here